# Count combinations of rows in a group with SQL

Tags: sql, statistics, combinations

I have a table with orders and their products:

```
+-------+---------+
| Order | Product |
+-------+---------+
| A     |       1 |
| A     |       2 |
| A     |       2 |
| A     |       3 |
| B     |       1 |
| B     |       3 |
| B     |       4 |
| C     |       1 |
| C     |       3 |
+-------+---------+
```

I want to count the occurrences, when two products are ordered together to identity popular product combinations:

```
+---------------+----------------+-------+
| First product | Second product | Count |
+---------------+----------------+-------+
|             1 |              2 |     1 |
|             1 |              3 |     3 |
|             1 |              4 |     1 |
|             2 |              3 |     1 |
|             2 |              4 |     0 |
|             3 |              4 |     0 |
+---------------+----------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a self join and group by:

```
select op1.product, op2.product, count(*)
from orderproduct op1 join
     orderprodut op2
     on op1.order = op2.order and
        op1.product < op2.product
group by op1.product, op2.product
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you want the most popular combinations, I don't see what combinations with `0` would be needed, so this does not include them.

The above counts all combinations (multiples within an order).  If you want to count orders, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
select op1.product, op2.product, count(distinct op1.order)
from orderproduct op1 join
     orderprodut op2
     on op1.order = op2.order and
        op1.product < op2.product
group by op1.product, op2.product
order by count(*) desc;
```

Or use `select distinct` with subqueries.  Which is faster depends on the number of duplicate products within orders.

Comment: you might want to use SELECT DISTINCT (Order,Product) in the FROM op1 and FROM op2 to avoid counting combinations twice within one order.

Comment: Thanks! This your answer with matthes remark is exactly what I need.